# How To Play .avi videos using url in android by programing

Tags: android, video, avi

How can I play .avi video in android? The video in coming from a url.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post it too.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can try the following code to play videos using URL

```
    String link="http://s1133.photobucket.com/albums/m590/Anniebabycupcakez/?action=view&amp; current=1376992942447_242.avi";
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

Using a VideoView just set the uri:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
```